# Unity create local variable for Time.DeltaTime for math calculations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, synchronization, execution

I recently thought about how to code in a better way. Currently, I'm doing math `calculations` and wondering if I should cache `Time.deltaTime` into an own variable for sake of synchronization.

```
float a = speed * Time.deltaTime;
float b = speed / Time.deltaTime;
float c = a - b;
```

Or

```
float deltaTime = Time.deltaTime;
float a = speed * deltaTime;
float b = speed / deltaTime;
float c = a - b;
```

This is just random code I made up, but the point is when calling `Time.deltaTime` is calling internal update.

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The interval in seconds from the last frame to the current one (Read Only).
    public static float deltaTime
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        get;
    }
```

Meaning not in sync, right? Obviously this is a minor thing, but still should you cache `Time.deltaTime` for staying in sync?

Comment: Sinply said, you wont see any difference. The gain would be it's shorter to write and if you used it in many places and you would decide to replace Time.deltaTime with another value like Time.fixedDeltaTime, then you'd have one place to change and it affects all the others. In terms of performance, you would save a dozen of ticks which is basically nothing.

Comment: `Meaning not in sync, right?`, wrong .. it will have the exact same value during the entire frame.

Answer (score -1):

[Everts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429487/everts) is right about the fact that in most cases it will not matter. [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) is probably right that in Unity specifically this value is fixed per frame. **But as a rule, good programming leaves no room for chance, so the second version will be more correct.**

```
float deltaTime = Time.deltaTime;
float a = speed * deltaTime;
float b = speed / deltaTime;
float c = a - b;
```

Imagine another case where we use a date, for example.

```
// The value for the key. This will be either the existing value for the key if
// the key is already in the dictionary, or the new value if the key was not in
// the dictionary.
var dateTime = dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, value: DateTime.Now);           

// This will always be true because DateTime.Now returns different value
if (DateTime.Now != dateTime)
{
    // Compares the existing value for the specified key with a specified value, and 
    // if they are equal, updates the key with a third value.
    _exceptionContainer.TryUpdate(key, newValue: DateTime.Now, comparisionValue: dateTime);

    // We have updated key with different datetime value than compared earlier.
}
```

At the beginning of the above code, we should write

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
```

And use the **now** variable instead of **DateTime.Now**.

Comment: Well for `DateTime.Now` this makes a lot sense because it is everytime calling the constructor of a quite expensive type in general ...you can't compare both directly .. `Time.deltaTime` is a single float so whether just using it again or allocating some local variable for it is more efficient is pretty much a micro optimisation / very depending on the specific use case ;) someone would need to benchmark these ^^

Comment: You write about a specific case I write about good practice. In my case there is no need to wonder if it will work. Optimizations are made when they are needed, not prematurely.